# MySQL Import only one column to existing table

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem.

I have a table which contains the following fields (example):

```
id, id2, id3, id4
```

Due to a mistake, I have accidently deleted all values of `id3`. (They are `NULL` now).

I have a second file (backup) which is a bit older, so it doesn't have the same count as the damaged table. The `id3` is present there.

How do I "join" these tables, to restore at least the bigger part? Insert `id3` ONLY to the damaged table from the non-damaged table?

I tried this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET `id3` = SELECT `id3` FROM table2
```

In my case, only phpMyAdmin or SQL Syntax solution (no console) would work...

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that one, two, or three of the ids define each row, then you can use `join`:

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on t1.id = t2.id
    set t1.id3 = t2.id3;
```

This assumes that `id` is unique in the two tables.  You might want to use a more complex expression:

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on t1.id = t2.id and t1.id2 = t2.id2 and t1.id4 = t2.id4
    set t1.id3 = t2.id3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `id` is an unique attribute.

You can simply run this query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET id3 = (SELECT id3 FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.id)
```